# Rendering React component in Redux application with React-Router v4

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

This is my first crack at trying to integrate React-Router4 into a React/Redux app.  I've been stuck on the first hurdle for a couple hours as I'm reading the docs and a (very good) CSS-Tricks article.

The issue is that the  won't render the 'Whatever' value I input at the component prop, which should be a component.

I've actually read almost entirely thru the (excellent) docs, beginning here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

And I've consulted this article: https://css-tricks.com/react-router-4/ 
Which also includes this Codepen (to see if I did something obvious/stupid):  https://codepen.io/bradwestfall/project/editor/XWNWge?preview_height=50&open_file=src/app.js

I'm just hoping someone on SO might be able to nudge me over this hump.  I was expecting to at least be able to render this very simply without any additional libraries or adjustment to my stores based on:  https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration

entry point, index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import store from './stores'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Home from './components/Home'
import TopStories from './components/TopStories'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

// app entry point
const app = (
    <Provider store={store.configure(null)}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/topstories" component={TopStories} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)

// virtual DOM render
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'))
```

TopStories.js component (renders ok in the '/' path if I switch it w/ Home)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default (props) => {
  return(
    <div>Top Stories component </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to test by typing the path into the browswer.... Duh.  I just needed to set up a quick link component and everything worked fine.